# Не могу сохранить сообщение пользователя Telegram боту как число

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, бот

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['calc'])
def text(chat_data):
    bot.send_message(chat_data.chat.id, 'В <b>Pyrocalc</b> есть множество типов калькуляторов! Чтобы использовать какой-либо из них, напишите в чат: «поиск n», «поиск i» ', parse_mode='html')
    @bot.message_handler()
    def text(chat_data):
        if chat_data.text == 'поиск n':
            bot.send_message(chat_data.chat.id, 'Пожалуйста, введите известное значение <b>i</b> в следующем сообщении.', parse_mode='html')
            Calculator.calcsave = chat_data.text
            i = Calculator.calcsave
            while i == 'поиск n':
                Calculator.calcsave = chat_data.text
                i = Calculator.calcsave
                print(i)
                if i > 0:
                    n = 2**i
                    bot.send_message(chat_data.chat.id, f'<b>N</b> = {n}', parse_mode='html')
                else:
                    bot.send_message(chat_data.chat.id, f'Ошибка! i должна быть больше нуля!')
```

В этом отрывке кода я пишу команду, бот на нее реагирует и просит ввести значение **i**, однако на этом моменте все ломается. Мне нужно чтобы сообщение сохранялось как **целое число**, чтобы бот мог возвести **2** в указанную мною степень. До этого у меня было много попыток сделать это, но безуспешно. Работаю с ботом в первый раз, надеюсь на помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from telebot import TeleBot
from telebot.types import Message

bot = TeleBot('ТОКЕН')

class Calculator:
    calcsave = None

@bot.message_handler(commands=['calc'])
def text(message: Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В <b>Pyrocalc</b> есть множество типов калькуляторов! Чтобы использовать какой-либо из них, напишите в чат: «поиск n», «поиск i» ', parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'поиск n')
def handle_search_n(message: Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пожалуйста, введите известное значение <b>i</b> в следующем сообщении.', parse_mode='html')
    Calculator.calcsave = 'поиск n'

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: Calculator.calcsave == 'поиск n')
def handle_i_value(message: Message):
    try:
        i = int(message.text)
        if i > 0:
            n = 2 ** i
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'<b>N</b> = {n}', parse_mode='html')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ошибка! i должна быть больше нуля!')
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пожалуйста, введите целое число для значения <b>i</b>.', parse_mode='html')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Рабочий вариант кода, который выполняет данную задачу. Возможно Вам нужно будет подкорректировать под себя.

Вместе цикла `while` для ожидания ответа, здесь используется `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)`.

Также добавил ответ на случай, когда введено не число или отрицательное число.

Чтобы преобразовать переменную в число, достаточно всего лишь воспользоваться функцией `int(название_переменной)`.

**upd:**
Возможно вот такой вариант программы Вам подойдёт и от него будет легче отталкиваться:

```
import telebot

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Для использования бота напиши команду /calc.')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['calc'])
def handle_calc(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Теперь введи два числа через пробел.')

    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_numbers) ## переход на следующий шаг;

def get_numbers(message):
    try:
        numbers = [int(num) for num in message.text.split()] ## берём оба числа;
        result = numbers[0] ** numbers[1] ## возводим первое в степень другого;
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Результат: {result}')
    except (ValueError, IndexError): ## в случае ошибки;
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка. Введены некорректные данные. Пожалуйста, повторите попытку.')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Пример:

```
\calc
>>> Теперь введи два числа через пробел.
8 2
>>> Результат: 64.0
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Однако, хочу спросить: для чего нужно еще одно "Message" ? (напр. ``def text(message: Message):``

Comment: Message - это тип данных, предоставляемый Telebot для представления сообщений, которые бот может получить от пользователей через API. Указание типа Message в определении функции помогает уточнить, что функция ожидает аргумент, который должен быть объектом типа Message. Сначала указываем параметр message, а затем тип этого параметра - Message.

Comment: Если данный ответ смог решить Ваш вопрос, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить галочкой ответ, тем самым указав, что это решение. Удачных разработок! Если будут вопросы, то пишите.

Comment: А не могли бы вы подсказать, как сделать запрос сразу двух значений? Я пробовал это на новой функции, однако выходит сразу 2 сообщения подряд, а после в терминале появляется ошибка. Очень надеюсь на помощь: необходимо доделать программу к понедельнику.

Comment: Приведите пример, как будет выглядеть правильная команда от пользователя и какой должен быть результат. Постараюсь помочь, как будет минутка.

Comment: Дополнил ответ полной, немного переписанной программой с нуля. Подозреваю, что Вы что-то подобное хотели реализовать.

Comment: Да вы волшебник! Не знаю как благодарить! Даже становится интересно, как вы всему научились) И еще: могу узнать, для чего нужно приписывать переход на следующий шаг?

Comment: И, небольшая корректировка: можно сделать так, чтобы второе число могло быть как целым, так и дробным?

Comment: Следующий шаг это я так условно назвал. Грубо говоря, бот получил команду \calc, затем отправил своё сообщение и ему нужно ожидать от пользователя действий, а потом что-то после этого сделать. Вот это и есть ожидание действий и потом указана функция, которая в скобках - get_numbers.
А научился, это сложно назвать. Просто мелкие проекты для себя пытался сделать и, пока разбирался, некоторое отложилось. Главное уметь искать информацию. У меня у самого постоянно не получается куча всего

Comment: Целое число преобразовывается через int(), вещественное (с плавающей точной, оно же с дробью) через float().

Comment: Спасибо! Но снова проблема: далее у меня идет еще одна команда, и когда я хочу ее ввести после того как нашел **n** в первой программе, бот продолжает отсылать просьбу ввести значение **i**. Есть возможность это исправить? попробовал несколько вариантов, но это ни на что не повлияло.

Comment: Чтобы не делать здесь огромную переписку, Вы можете интересующие вопросы задать мне в телеграмме: https://t.me/mrBars1k_nya
Как у меня появится свободная минутка, я отвечу.